# Vanilla JS, how to manage different scripts for different partials/views

Tags: javascript, html, template-engine

Example:

- I have a website and I'm using a templating engine (i.e. Handlebars, EJS, Pug...)
- I have my views split into smaller partials (navigator, footer, etc...)
- I have short JS scripts in different files for the navigator and for the footer (nav.js, footer.js...)

What is the best way to manage and run these scripts on the website?

What I've been doing so far is the following:

- add each script to a global obj

  ```
  // nav.js
  my_scripts = my_scripts || {};
  my_scripts.nav = {
    // navigator script
  }
  ```

  ```
  // footer.js
  my_scripts = my_scripts || {};
  my_scripts.footer = {
    // footerscript
  }
  ```
- concatenate all the scripts files into one
- use only one script tag in the base template to import the concatenated file
- add a short snippet of code to the navigator and the footer partials to activate the needed scripts. Something like:

  ```
  // footer.ejs
  script>
  my_scripts.footer.init();
  /script>
  ```

I don't particularly like this because it involves adding small js snippets inside every and each template I need to run a script in.

Another option is to import each script file in the related partial instead of concatenating them all, but it doesn't feel right.

To wrap it up, here is the question again: what is the best way to manage different scripts for different partials/views/pages without using a framework?

Comment: namespacing the content *(avoid polluting the global namespace)* concat the files, minify and load only the concatenated minified script. Or take a look into the different module loader for JS to process these tasks for you. Oh, and check out the DOMContentLoaded event to init your snippets.

Comment: Hi @Thomas! Good point about avoiding pollution. About the rest, that's exactly what I'm doing, all automated with Grunt, But that still doesn't answer my question on if there is a way to achieve that without having to call my scripts from each template on DOMContentLoaded,